# "Class App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\FrontendController does not exist"

Tags: php, laravel

I installed a laravel script. but a page not worked and appear

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View:
>   /mylocal/core/resources/views/admin/users/servicePrice.blade.php)

for this line:

> ```
> <th>{{ $item->service->name }}</th>
> ```

this is the file codes:

```
<div class="tile">
    @include('admin.layouts.flash')
    <h3 class="tile-title">Service Price Details</h3>
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('store.service.price', $user_id) }}">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>
            @foreach($items as $item)
            <tr>
                <th>{{ $item->category->name }}</th>
                <th>{{ $item->service->name }}</th>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="{{ $item->id }}">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="price[]" value="{{ $item->price }}">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text">{{ $general->currency_symbol }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
        <div class="tile-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" type="submit"><i
                        class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The `service` relation of the `item` object is null or something other than an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your relation return a object or not.

```
 <th>
  @if($item->service)
         {{ $item->service->name }}
  @endif
 </th>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share the content of array $items.Please make sure you have a service array in $items array and also make sure the name variable exists in service array. 
and can you show me the result of this:
var_dump($items);